# save byte array as .mp4 file and play it in VideoView android

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I Have captured a video using my custom video activity and encoded it to base64 using this method

```
private String encodeVideoTobase64(Uri uri , int index)
{
    String videodata     = "";
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };

    Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    String videoPath;
    try{
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        videoPath       = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        videoPath = PathsOfVideos.get(index);
    }
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        FileInputStream v_input = new FileInputStream(videoPath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream objByteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] byteBufferString = new byte[1024];
        for (int readNum; (readNum = v_input.read(byteBufferString)) != -1;) 
        {
            objByteArrayOS.write(byteBufferString, 0, readNum);
            System.out.println("read " + readNum + " bytes,");
        }

       videodata = MyBase64.encodeBytes(byteBufferString);//Base64.encodeToString(objByteArrayOS.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return videodata;
}
```

Then I sent the encoded video to the server.

Now I want to get the video base64 string , decode it and display it in a video view . 
I have tried convert base64 string to byte array then save it to the mobile then display it in the video view using this code.

```
protected void showInstVideo(int pos) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_video);

    //Decode String To Video With mig Base64.
    String encodedString = r.getRecipeInstructions().get(pos).getVideoStr();
    if (encodedString.compareTo("")!=0) {
        byte[] decodedBytes = MiGBase64.decodeFast(encodedString.getBytes());

        try {
            Date date=new Date();
            String filename="/rec"+ date.toString().replace(" ", "_").replace(":", "_")+".mp4";
            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File myDir  = new File(root+"/MyAppName");
            if (!myDir.exists())
                myDir.mkdir();
            File file = new File (myDir, filename);

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            out.write(decodedBytes);
            out.close();

            VideoView instvideo     = (VideoView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.vvdetails);
            MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
            mediaController.setAnchorView(instvideo);
            Uri video = Uri.parse(file.getPath());
            instvideo.setVideoURI(video);

            if (video != null )
            {
                dialog.show();
                instvideo.start();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("Error", e.toString()); 
        }
    }


}
```

But the folder /MyAppName is not created so the video not saved and of course as a result I can't play the video .

Could you please help me to find what I am missing ?
Thanks in advance

Note: The code runs correctly and doesn't catch any exception

Comment: Have you added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> permission

Comment: Yes this permission exists. But there something strange happens, I found ALL the created folders appear suddenly. I don't know What was the reason that was making them to not appear instantaneously.. Do You have any Idea ?

Comment: Yeah..File operations takes some what more time..you need to use AsynchTask For this..And check after onPostExecute is Completed

Comment: OOHhh My GOD!! this way I can't play the video when the user wants to play it instantaneously :O. Is there a way to play bytearray video without saving it to the device ?

Comment: I dont think so its possible in android..you need to save then only play.

Comment: Thanks @Kalyan pvs for helping me :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `mkdir()` you can also use `mkdirs()`. `mkdirs()` will create all the directories till last directory in given path.

Replace this code:

```
File myDir  = new File(root + File.separator + "MyAppName");
myDir.mkdirs();
File file = new File (myDir.getAbsolutePath(), filename);
```

With:

```
File myDir  = new File(root+"/MyAppName");
if (!myDir.exists())
    myDir.mkdir();
File file = new File (myDir, filename);
```

Comment: I found ALL the created folders appear suddenly. I don't know What was the reason that was making them to not appear instantaneously.. Do You have any Idea ?